# Type of switch?

Tags: switch

I have a lamp shaped like a boat that has 2 separate bulbs. Dim bulbs in the cabin and a regular 45w lamp in the sail. The switch rotates to turn on either cabin, lamp, or both in that order. I need to replace the switch but don't know what to search for.

Comment: That would be a "3 Way Rotary Switch, 4 Position (L1, L2, L1 L2, Off)."

Comment: Also known as a "2-circuit" switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a switch that looks as follows:

[image]

[This particular unit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BVXVZO) comes with pigtail leads that make it easy to connect into the existing wiring in a light fixture.

The switching configuration is specified as:

Single Pole Triple Throw, OFF-ON(P)-ON(N)-ON(N+P)